# Is it possible to combine all SVG icons into one file for performance in HTML?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a bunch of different SVG files in my public folder. These svg are shown using the `image-mask: url(/icon.svg)` attribute.

This is fine if I only had one svg but I have 20 different icons. Is there a way to combine it into something like sprites for regular JPG images?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out SVG sprites? Icon fonts are done that way, you could use the same approach with any group of SVGs.

Comment: Here's a good article on getting started with SVG spriting: https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/

Answer (score 5):

One performance approach you can look at is adding your **SVG**s to your CSS Stylesheet as **Data URIs**.

This has one downside:

- it increases the size of your CSS stylesheet

but the following two advantages:

- You won't need to undertake the server round-trips to collect the SVGs
- When the browser caches your stylesheet, all your inlined Data URI SVGs will be cached, simultaneously, along with the stylesheet

This will almost certainly give you a noticeable performance boost.

---

Let's have a look at how this might work.

Here's an **SVG** for a five-pointed star:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="260" height="245">
<path transform="scale(0.75)" d="m55, 237 74-228 74, 228L9, 96h240" />
</svg>
```

And here's that same **SVG** as a **Data URI**:

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%20width="260"%20height="245"%3E%3Cpath%20transform="scale(0.75)"%20d="m55,237%2074-228%2074,228L9,96h240"%20/%3E%3C/svg%3E
```

You can see that after the `data:image/svg+xml,` prefix, the **Data URI SVG** is almost exactly the same, except:

- the angle brackets `<` & `>` have been swapped for `%3C` & `%3E` percent codes

---

Finally, here's that **Data URI SVG** in action in the CSS below...

**Working Example:**

```css
.image-without-mask,
.image-with-mask {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}


.image-with-mask {

  /* N.B. -webkit- prefix required for Chrome, Edge, Safari and Opera (but not Firefox) */
  -webkit-mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%20width="260"%20height="245"%3E%3Cpath%20transform="scale(0.75)"%20d="m55,237%2074-228%2074,228L9,96h240"%20/%3E%3C/svg%3E');

  mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%20width="260"%20height="245"%3E%3Cpath%20transform="scale(0.75)"%20d="m55,237%2074-228%2074,228L9,96h240"%20/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}
```

```html
<img class="image-without-mask" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x180/0000FF/FFFFFF" />

<img class="image-with-mask" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x180/0000FF/FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: What is the recommended tool for decode svg to base uri?

Comment: We only need to swap the angle brackets `<` & `>` for `%3C` & `%3E` percent codes. That's it. Any no-frills search and replace will be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use tools to combine multiple SVG files into a single sprite sheet using  tags. This is supported by all modern browsers.

You can do this from a Node.js script using svgstore:
https://github.com/svgstore/svgstore

There's also a cli variant you can use from a npm (package.json) script or from the command line:
https://github.com/svgstore/svgstore-cli

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/its-2019-lets-end-the-debate-on-icon-fonts-vs-svg-icons/#:~:text=How%20To%20Build%20Your%20SVG%20Icon%20System%3F](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/its-2019-lets-end-the-debate-on-icon-fonts-vs-svg-icons/#:%7E:text=How%20To%20Build%20Your%20SVG%20Icon%20System%3F)

In a nutshell:

1. Convert an icon font to SVG using tool like https://onlinefontconverter.com/
2. Edit the SVG by selecting just the symbols you need using tools like

   - https://icomoon.io/app/
   - http://fontastic.me/
   - http://fontello.com/
   - https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-blast
3. Use syntax like `<svg class="icon-twitter"><use xlink:href="#icon-twitter"></use></svg>` to address parts of the locally included SVG.